# CoreOS update failed

Tags: coreos

When running the update command for CoreOS I get an update failed error. According to [the documentation](http://todo) this means that there are no updates found. This shouldn't be the case as the version I'm running is `CoreOS stable (647.2.0)`.

```
update_engine_client -update

$> cat /etc/os-release
NAME=CoreOS
ID=coreos
VERSION=647.2.0
VERSION_ID=647.2.0
BUILD_ID=
PRETTY_NAME="CoreOS 647.2.0"
ANSI_COLOR="1;32"
HOME_URL="https://coreos.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://github.com/coreos/bugs/issues"

$> cat /etc/coreos/update.conf
GROUP=stable
SERVER=https://customer.update.core-os.net/v1/update/
```

How can I trigger the update proces?

Answer (score 3):

Running `update_engine_client -check_for_update` should bypass any rate limits and update immediately. See https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/update-strategies.html#manually-triggering-an-update for more details.

Comment: Hi, for me running `sudo update-engine-client -check-for-update` does absolutely nothing

Comment: @Alex you wrote -check-for-update not -check_for_update